# C# .Net Powershell Exception when excecuting in debug log

Tags: c#, powershell, exception, visual-studio-2015, powershell-4.0

When I execute a PowerShell 4.0 script from C#, in the output of the debugger, I get an exception that I don't get when I execute the same script in Windows PowerShell ISE.

I referenced the [Nuget package of PowerShell](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management.Automation/) :

```
<package id="Microsoft.PowerShell.5.ReferenceAssemblies" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
```

Here's my C# code :

```
    static void Main(string[] strArgs)
    {
        using (Stream strmPowerScript = new MemoryStream(Properties.Resources.Test))
        {
            using (StreamReader srPowerScript = new StreamReader(strmPowerScript))
            {
                string strScriptPs = srPowerScript.ReadToEnd();
                using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
                {
                    runspace.Open();

                    using (PowerShell objPowerScript = PowerShell.Create())
                    {
                        objPowerScript.Runspace = runspace;
                        Command cmdPowerScript = new Command(strScriptPs, true);
                        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
                        pipeline.Commands.Add(cmdPowerScript);

                        pipeline.Invoke();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's my PowerShell code :

```
   $msg = "testVal"
   $ReportFile = "C:\Temp\Diag\test_err.txt"
   write-output "$msg"  >> $ReportFile
```

The first exception is :

```
'System.DllNotFoundException' in System.Management.Automation.dll
```

I get this error every time I run a PowerShell script. No matter what's inside the script. I don't know why this error happens.

The second error happens if the file C:\Temp\Diag\test_err.txt does not exist :

```
'System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException' in System.Management.Automation.dll
```

Why does this happen? The file is not there, but the command creates it...

The third error is :

```
'System.Management.Automation.Host.HostException' in System.Management.Automation.dll
```

This one happens to write-output, if I remove this line the error goes away. I know that the HostException is supposed to raise if I call a write-host or a read-host, but write-output doesn't even show anything when I execute it from Windows PowerShell ISE. I tried Out-File with the same result. I tried `Invoke-Expression "cmd.exe /c (""$msg"" >> $ReportFile)"` again with the same error.

Those exceptions appear only in the output of Visual Studio's debugger. The file is created if it doesn't exist and the text is appended if the file exists.

This is a test. My actual script is way bigger than that and throw an large amount of errors like that.

Also, I want a way to get those errors and show the inner exception, so I can see why they raise. I tried to get `pipeline.Error`, but it's empty. I tried in the PowerShell script to call `$error` but it's also empty.

The version of PowerShell is :

```
$PSVersionTable

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                      
----                           -----                                                                                                                                      
PSVersion                      4.0                                                                                                                                        
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                        
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                                                                                                                    
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                                                            
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.16406                                                                                                                             
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}                                                                                                                       
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

But the version of the nuget package is `6.1.7601.17515` and the version in the package.config is `Microsoft.PowerShell.5`. Can this be related?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello! Try to connect dll: C:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Management.Automation\1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Management.Automation.dll and than : using System.Threading.Tasks; 
Maybe this will help.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer, but my contract there is finished :S I just worked with it till then end.